# How do I determine the list of hosts available in a network/subnet in solaris10?

Tags: solaris-10

I would like to know the list of hosts available in solaris 10 . In linux we can do the magic with nmap . But I am not sure with solaris .

Many thanks in Advance !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solaris can use nmap as well, though it just isn't part of the native distribution. Just download, install it, and you're good to go.

Many Linux built-in tools are not built-in on Solaris, like nmap, lsof, and many others.